# What is 'Should the conditional mechanism be an integral part of the exit' means when it comes the language design?

Tags: lua, language-design

I had an assignment for my Programming Language homework which makes us to experiment over the language **Lua**. One of the aspect of the language we required to experiment over is **should the conditional mechanism be an integral part of the exit (conditional or unconditional exit)?** So my friends and I discussed it as it is a question of whether the loop construction of the program needs controller or not. For example in Lua

```
for i = 0 , 5, 1 do
   print("Something")
end
```

loop statement chooses conditional exit according to our discussion with friends. On the other hand, I think it is not a design choice since the generally every programming language  chooses conditional exit. So why it is a design choice for the programming language? If we think wrong about design decision can you explain what is this design decision about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question

I will assume you're referring to the following notes (based on a quick search):

> It is sometimes convenient for a programmer to choose a location for loop control other than the top or bottom of the loop.
> Design issues:
>
> - Should the conditional mechanism be an integral part of the exit?
> - Should only one control body be exited, or can enclosing loops also be exited?
>   C and C++ have unconditional unlabeled exits (`break`)
>   Java, Perl, and C# have unconditional labeled exits (`break` in Java and C#, `last` in Perl)
>   [...]

- https://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/kyang/2016/Fall/CMPS401/ClassNotes/CMPS401ClassNotesChap08.pdf

### Loops

Lua offers 5 looping constructs: The classic `while` loop for loops that are supposed to run zero or more times, the `repeat`-`until` loop (comparable to `do`-`while`, except the condition is inverted) for loops that run one or more times, the numeric `for var = from, to, step` loop from your example for iterating over evenly spaced numbers in a range known beforehand, the very flexible generic `for var1, var2, ... in iterator, invariant_state, control_var` loop, and finally, tail recursion using `function f() --[[body]] return f() end`.

### `break`

Tail recursion is the odd one out here so let's start with the other loops. Given a `while`/`repeat` or `for` loop, you can use the `break` loop control statement to exit the innermost loop. You could use this to implement `for i = 1, 7 do print(i) end` as follows without using a loop condition:

```lua
local i = 1
while true do
    print(i)
    if i == 7 then
        break
    end
    i = i + 1
end
```

(note that this is not a particularly useful example).

### Breaking multiple loops

To exit multiple loops, you'd have to use either a `goto` or a `return`:

```lua
for i = 1, 10 do
    for j = 1, 10 do
        if frobnicate(i, j) then
            goto after_loops
        end
    end
end
::after_loops::
...
```

using a `return`:

```lua
(function()
    for i = 1, 10 do
        for j = 1, 10 do
            if frobnicate(i, j) then
                return
            end
        end
    end
end)()
...
```

(often this would lead you to properly extract the nested loop into a named function)

Other workarounds use boolean variables stuffed into the loop conditions/iterators to achieve the same effect, but this is rather dirty (and also slightly inefficient). `goto` is the cleanest solution here.

### `continue`

**Lua does not have a `continue`.** The simplest workaround again is to wrap the chunk you want to continue in a function and call `return`:

```lua
for k1, v1 in pairs(t1) do
    for k2, v2 in pairs(t2) do
        (function()
             if foo(k1, v2) then
                 return -- "continue"
             end
             bar(k2, v1)
             foobar(k1, v1)
        end)()
    end
end
```

Caveat: You're creating an anonymous function in every loop iteration. It is again flexible enough to allow continuing multiple loops. Again, a `goto` is the cleaner solution:

```lua
for k1, v1 in pairs(t1) do
    for k2, v2 in pairs(t2) do
        if foo(k1, v2) then
            goto continue
        end
        bar(k2, v1)
        foobar(k1, v1)
        ::continue::
    end
end
```

Finally, if you use (tail-)recursive functions and want to jump out of multiple functions at once, you can use `coroutine.yield` for that; in fact, `coroutine.wrap` is usually used for complex (recursive) iterators, as you'd otherwise have to explicitly manage the program state (stack) iteratively rather than managing it implicitly in the call stack.

### Design decisions involved

- Lua provides plenty of looping (condition at begin/end, numeric for, generic for) constructs (excepting tail recursion); usually one of the 4 suits the task well.
- Lua provides a `break` statement for exiting a single loop.
- Lua **does not provide a `continue` statement**.
- Lua provides a **powerful `goto`** which can be used to the same effect as breaking/continuing of labeled loops in other programming languages. This serves to eliminate the need for `continue` at slight verbosity.
- Lua has powerful closures with tail recursion support which can be used to work around limitations. Tail recursion is the first and foremost looping construct of Lisp-family functional languages; rather than having to explicitly `break` the loop, you can start the next loop iteration (function call) using `return func(...)` at arbitrary places, skipping the rest of the function body. If you use upvalues, you don't even have to pass parameters.